# How do I find one Table

Tags: sql

If I have one Table `Employee` where

`EmployeeID`,

`EmployeeName`,

`FirstName`,

`LastName`,

`ManagerID`,

`ManagerName`

here `ManagerID` have also `EmployeeID`.

Employee work under Manager.

How do I find from table `Employee`

`FirstName`,

`EmployeeName`,

`ManagerName`

**where one manager have not more then 6 employee**.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you're asking but have a look at the `HAVING` clause ~ https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-having-clause.htm

Comment: Please add  `DDL` and [MCVE]

Comment: You need to write what have you tried so far till now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT FirstName,EmployeeName, ManagerName
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.ManagerID IN
(
    SELECT ManagerID
    FROM Employee 
    GROUP BY ManagerID
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 6

)
```

Answer (score 0):

/* Considering there may be top level employees where manager id will be null. Code in MSSQL */

```
SELECT FirstName, EmployeeName, ManagerName 
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ManagerId 
    FROM Employee 
    WHERE ManagerId IS NOT NULL 
    GROUP BY ManagerId
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 6  
) t  
ON (e.ManagerId = t.ManagerId OR e.ManagerId IS NULL);
```

/* If we don't care whether the manager id is null or not then */

```
SELECT FirstName, EmployeeName, ManagerName 
FROM Employee e INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT ManagerId 
    FROM Employee 
    GROUP BY ManagerId
    HAVING COUNT(*) <= 6  
) t  
ON (e.ManagerId = t.ManagerId);
```